# A better way to make a custom curved app bar in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-appbar

I am trying to make a custom curved app bar, look like the example below
[image]

and after many tries here is my shot

[image]

source code :

```dart
class CustomShapeBorder extends ContinuousRectangleBorder {
  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) {
    final double innerCircleRadius = 150.0;

    Path path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0, rect.height);
    path.cubicTo(rect.width / 1.5 - 40, rect.height + innerCircleRadius - 40, rect.width / 1.5 + 40,
        rect.height + innerCircleRadius - 40, rect.width / 1.5 + 75, rect.height + 50);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
        rect.width / 1.5 + (innerCircleRadius / 2) + 30, rect.height + 35, rect.width, rect.height);
    path.lineTo(rect.width, 0.0);
    path.close();

    return path;
  }
}
```

is there an easy way to make it for example SVG.

Comment: I think `Path` is best way to modify shape and `Path` is very useful whenever we need curved in widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could come up with this result:

[image]

Here is the `Path`:

```
double x = 150, y = 45, r = 0.5;
Path path = Path()
  ..addRRect(RRect.fromRectAndCorners(rect))
  ..moveTo(rect.bottomRight.dx - 30, rect.bottomCenter.dy)
  ..relativeQuadraticBezierTo(((-x / 2)+(x/6)) * (1 - r), 0, -x / 2 * r, y * r)
  ..relativeQuadraticBezierTo(-x / 6 * r, y * (1 - r), -x / 2 * (1 - r), y * (1 - r))
  ..relativeQuadraticBezierTo(((-x / 2)+(x/6)) * (1 - r), 0, -x / 2 * (1 - r), -y * (1 - r))
  ..relativeQuadraticBezierTo(-x/6*r , -y * r, -x / 2 * r, -y * r);
```

And here is a good article to see the basics to make shapes: [Paths in Flutter: A Visual Guide](https://medium.com/flutter-community/paths-in-flutter-a-visual-guide-6c906464dcd0)

Comment: Thank you, it's a little bit to understand well Path

Comment: can you please answer this question as well.. its related to custom paint and i'm almost there but something is missing and need you input so if it's possible please look in to it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78073980/using-custom-paint-to-achieve-the-given-shape